# Calculating Kryptonian speed in the movie "Man of Steel"

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, speed, estimation

This is my first question, so I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask but:

How would you go about calculating the speed of Kryptonians in the movie [*Man of Steel* (2013)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0770828/)?

Specifically, I'm referring to [this](https://youtu.be/_4phfu8_CNg?t=21s) scene,
where Faora-Ul blitzes the soldiers in quick succession. I was trying to figure out how to calculate her speed in that scene, but given the camera angle, I'm not quite sure how to go about doing that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A rough calculation can be done using this frame :

[image]

On the far left we have Faora and on the far right the soldier she is attacking in the next scene.

If we assume the height of a soldier to 1m80 then they are at a distance of 10m

It takes her 4 frames to cover that distance in the next scene and the video is 24 fps therefore the speed is

$$
V = \frac{10m}{4/24 s} = 60 m/s = 216 km/h
$$

An interesting calculation would be the air friction on her.